# Prevent shared session between tabs or same browser windows

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have to fix this basic web application that allows viewing data, say customers data, and editing it using Tomcat and Spring framework. My problem happens when I try editing different customers data from different browser tabs at the same time; the edited data gets mixed. If I open customer A to be edited in one tab, I open customer B in another tab, then I go back editing customer A and save it, this last changes for customer A are applied to customer B.

Investigating a bit this problem happens because the customer data is stored in the session, but this session is shared between the different tabs. So when I open customer A in one tab, this customer is stored in the session but when I open customer B in another tab, this latest is the one stored. Thus, when I finish editing customer A and I submit the form, the changes are applied to the customer found in the session, customer B.

I see here different solutions to my problem. One solution would be preventing users from opening our application in multiple tabs, but it gets too complicated and I feel it's dirty. The other solution would be to simply using different sessions for the different tabs, but I am not sure how can I achieve this. Reading this forum I found another post that mentions using setting in the context.xml file of the Tomcat 'cookies=false' but then the whole application fails and I don't want to touch more than necessary in a code that is not mine. Also I see it is mentioned to use HTML5 SessionStorage, but I could not find any good example implementing this.

I think this must be a common problem, shared session between tabs, and that it must have a common solution. What solution would be suitable in this case?

**EDIT:**

Let's say I have this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long customerId, Map modelMap) {
    Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
    modelMap.put("customer", customer);
    return "customer";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, OutputStream outputStream,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    save(customer);
}
```

I am not sure what does the `modelMap.put("customer", customer);` but I assume is where the customer is stored in the session. I can successfully add a hidden field in the jsp page and retrieve the Customer from the database in the save method by adding `@RequestParam(value = "customerId", required = true) Long customerId,` now my question is, the Customer I get in the save method with `@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer` is the customer submitted from the jsp or the one stored in the session? And furthermore, if this is the one stored in the session, how do I retrieve the changed made in the jsp?

Comment: None of your solutions is the right one. The right solution would be to avoid storing the customer in the session in the first place. Just pass the ID of the customer you're editing, using a hidden input field. Then get the customer from your database thanks to this ID, and update it. If you really want your customer in the session, then don't use the same key for all customers. Use the ID of the customer as part of the key (like "customer.<id>" for example), and once again, pass this ID using a hidden input field.

Comment: I thought so too and tested this already successfully but I didn't want to change a code that is not mine more than necessary; it looked like a nightmare to make all the unit tests run well again. I thought it would be good to ask what is the standard way of doing it.

Comment: @danielsp there is no standard way to fix horrible design. The right way is to invest time, money and effort to fix it. Usually, you end up with patches on top of hacks on top of duct tape instead because you had to do repeated quick and dirty fixes.

Comment: I tried to go for the hidden field. The problem here is that the Customer object passed in the save method is always the Custom object generated for the latest tab opened so it only contains the changes in this tab. The problem is that in the jsp file there is a <jsp:useBean id="customer" and this id cannot be dynamic according to the specifications it is not possible so I cannot get this object in the client with id="customer_"+hiddenField. I cannot believe this becomes so complex.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to implement this? As you possible noticed almost no one do that. Not always, but often, this is a sign your intent is initially wrong.
For me personally, having different sessions in different tabs is totally confusing. I'd rather use an "Incognito mode" or another browser. Or think about some UI changes.

E.g. "Open in new tab" would work not in usual way if required a separate session.